# How are they in the "centre" of the town?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

Let me set a scene. Riker and company beam down to Jouret IV. Behind them is a rocky wilderness with no sign of blast damage. In front of them is a giant matte painting of a miles-wide crater. Riker asks O'Brien if the coordinates are right and gets the response

> "you're in the **centre** of town"

If they're in the centre of town, **why isn't there the other half of the town behind them?** Did the Borg only take *half the town* and put rocks and plants over the rest?

**What happened to the rest of the town?**

---

[image: Crater]

Comment: Welcome to SciFi&Fantasy: SE. I'm sorry but I can't read that easily, can you add some punctuation pls?

Comment: @AthenaWidget better now?

Answer (score 2):

You have to admit that they're pretty darned close.

[image]

Obviously he could have dumped them **right into the middle of the crater filled with jagged metal, radiation and gas** but that would have been the sort of thing that earns you a week doing level 2 diagnostics of the turbolift shafts.

Comment: Gotta love a smartypants :-)

Comment: The real answer is the dialogue wasn't well thought out.  I agree if they were in the center of town they would have to be inside the mat painting.  Richard's "approx 100 meters away" is not well thought out either as the town would only be about 1000 square meters in area.  If you really want to overthink it you need to consider what the center of town is measured as.  Is it the geographic center, town hall or plaza, or the density of the structures and population.  As always you should remember MST3K on the subject of inconsistancies in sci-fi.  "...just a show you should really just relax."